# N distinct elements, is a permutation or all possible subsets larger?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

Given N distinct elements (where N is large), how do I determine if a permutation of it is larger, or if all possible subsets is larger?

I eyeballed it and it seems like the permutations would be bigger. It seems like this subset is largest: N choose N/2, but this subset is kind of close to $2^{N/2}$, which is clearly a lost smaller than $N!$. Not sure how to prove this though

Comment: You can prove that $2^{N/2}$ is less than $N!$ by induction

Comment: Check this:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3925362/how-to-prove-that-n2n-holds-for-all-n3/3925454#3925454

Comment: Consider also Stirling approximation of $n! $ for large $n$

Answer (score 1):

If you mean whether the size of the set of all possible permutations of an N-element set is bigger than the size of the set of all possible subsets, i.e. whether $N!>2^N$ then the answer is yes, if $N>3$. That it is wrong for $N=1,2,3$ is a simple computation. The actual statement follows by induction:

1. The induction start: we take $N=4$ and obtain $N!=24>16=2^4$
2. Now suppose the statement holds for $N-1$, then since clearly $N>2$ we have $$N!=N(N-1)!>2(N-1)!>2\cdot 2^{N-1}=2^N$$ where the last inequality follows from the induction hypothesis.

Comment: How do we show that 2^n is the set of all possible subsets?

Answer (score 0):

The orders are $2^n$ and $n!$.  But $n!\gt 2^n$ for $n\gt3$, by inspection.  So there are more permutations, in this case.

Comment: How can we show that the set of all subset order is 2^n?

Comment: That's a good question.  The key is that for each of the $n$ elements there's $2$ options: either it goes into the subset or not.